# sudo apt-update while on VPN

Tags: apt, update-manager

I have been having trouble running the sudo apt-get update on Ubantu, while on a VPN. I have looked at a few other threads which suggest changing the file /etc/resolve.conf to nameserver 8.8.8.8, which results in the following:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
....
```

And if I configure nameserver so that it matches the VPN DNS:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Connection failed 
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Connection failed 
.....
```

Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: check   that your vpn settings does not have a killswitch, can you ping anything? since a long time ago we now use sudo apt update, not apt-get.